# what information is provided to the miner with the transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, contract-invocation, miner

I am wondering what information is provided to the miner with a transaction that needs to invoke a contract?
I thought about Gas, GasPrice, name of function to invoke and input.

But, whether the miner can access to the source code of the contract before executing the transaction? Whether the miner will be able to know what operations (e.g., storage to memory or just simple arithmetic operations) need to be executed?

Any good source to learn about such technical details about this?

Answer (score 0):

A miner to execute a contract it has to have access to the contract code and the contract storage. Then it will execute the contract using the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM).

The formal specification is in the Yellow Paper (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), it has plenity of low level details. A more high level approach is the Ethereum White paper (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper).

Comment: Thanks! i read both papers. my question is what the miner can know about transactions apart from their gas and gas price? is he able to access the code to see what is he going to run?